# Swipe-to-delete doesn't work on iPad

Tags: uitableview, ios6, swipe

I have UITableView with custom cell, Swipe-to-delete works just fine in iPad simulator but it never worked on iPad device.

Here's my code:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        return YES;
}

- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        if(_itemsArray == nil)
            NSLog(@"\n\nNIL ARRAY\n\n");
        NSLog(@"\nindexPath.row = %d\nItemsArray Count:%d",indexPath.row,_itemsArray.count);
        int row = [[[_itemsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]valueForKey:@"itemRow"] integerValue];
        [_itemsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [[self delegate]didDeletedBillItemRow:row];
    }
    [tableView endUpdates];
}
```

I also implemented layoutSubviews in my custom cell controller:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
}
```

What do you think the problem is?

Comment: I recommend debugging your code on the actual device this may sometimes give you a better hint. As you already put it, it works in simulator.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I already did, the problem is the iPad doesn't recognize any swipe on the table, I checked userInteractionEnabled and it's YES, this is so strange. I also added swipe gesture recognizer to another table and also it's not recognizable in real device! but works fine on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

May or may not work for you. I spend a while figuring out why it was not working for me. I realized it was because the cell user interaction enabled was off. I don't know why it was still working on the simulator but that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I only changed the property of selection mode during editing to "Single Selection During Editing" instead of "Multiple Selection During Editing" and I'm now able to delete the rows using swipe-to-delete perfectly.